# Path contains matching

Tags: apigee

I would like to execute the flow based on a contains match

```
<Flow name="do_something_flow">
        <Description/>
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <FaultRules/>
                <Name>do_something</Name>
            </Step>
        </Request>
        <Response/>
        <Condition>request.path MatchesPath "/**/india/blr/**"</Condition>
    </Flow>
```

The flow should execute when ever the request path contains */india/blr* for example

```
/v1/x1/india/blr/z1
/v1/x1/india/blr
/v1/india/blr
/india/blr
```

The above path expression does not work for the second and last path- where URL starts and ends with subpath.
What i really needs is

```
request.path contains "/india/blr"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pre-flow you can have a custom javacallout policy to match the path with contains condition. 
Then populate a variable
Use that variable in the condition of your flow.

It is a round about way - but works in absence of a "contains" operator in apigee path conditions.

Alternately, you can try JavaRegex which is supported by apigee in conditions. http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/conditions-reference

~~ (    JavaRegex operator )    Matches a javax.util.regex compliant regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your condition statement as

```
<Condition>request.path ~ "/india/blr/**"</Condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

To catch all 4 cases, you could use this:

```
<Condition>request.path MatchesPath "**/india/blr**"</Condition>
```

However, this is a overly broad and will also match paths like this:

/india/blrx/asd

So, to be more precise, you probably want this:

```
<Condition>request.path MatchesPath "**/india/blr/**" or request.path MatchesPath "**/india/blr"</Condition>
```

Comment: neat hack similar to java regex :-)